# Translating SQL Query to ActiveRecord and Rendering as a Table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to translate a raw SQL query in my model to use ActiveRecord Query Interface. I think that I translated the query correctly, but I cannot transform it to an array in order to render it.

Here is my model:

```
class Pgdb < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = 'test'

  if Rails.env.development?
    establish_connection :pg_development
  end

  def self.getInfo(name)
    get = Pgdb.where(city: "New York")
    get_a = get.to_a
    get_a
  end
end
```

The raw SQL query, which I was able to render, was:

```
get = connection.query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE city = "New York")
```

As the above code indicates, I am accessing an external PostgreSQL database and have tried to convert the ActiveRecord object to an array using `#to_a` but this isn't working. When I try to render it in my view:

```
<% @info.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <% row.each do |element| %>
      <td><%= element %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I get an error: `undefined method 'each' for #<Pgdb:0x007fd37af79040>`. I have tried using `to_a` on the object in different places in the code but nothing has worked.

**Controller**

```
def index
end

def new
  @thing = Thing.new
end

def create
  @info = Pgdb.getInfo(@thing.something)
  render :index
end
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Why are you creating a model named `Pgdb`? Rails models are objects which are supposed to reflect the domain objects in your application (like User, Car, Company..) not the database connection itself.

Comment: I have an external database that I need to access on AWS. What's an alternative way to access this database? The connection works fine, although your point may be valid that it's conventionally incorrect.

Comment: Could you include your controller code for the method that renders this view? In particular, what value is assigned to @info?

Comment: @amar47shah - added controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the error `undefined method 'each'` for an instance of `Pgdb` because your code is trying to iterate over the instance's data attributes in this line:

```
<% row.each do |element| %>
```

ActiveRecord instances are not collections of attributes that you can iterate over. Instead, they are objects that respond to messages named for their attributes. In other words, you can do this:

```
p = Pgdb.first
p.city # because the underlying table has a `city` attribute
```

but you can't do this:

```
p.each { |attribute| puts attribute }
```

However, ActiveRecord provides the [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes) accessor for just this very thing. The `attributes` method returns a hash that you can iterate over with the `each` method. Therefore, you *can* do this:

```
p.attributes.each { |key, value| puts "#{key}: #{value}" }
```

In your view, you can substitute the inner loop with:

```
<% row.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <td><%= "#{key}: #{value}" %></td>
<% end %>
```

And this should render the attributes for your instance of `Pgdb`.

By the way, it is not necessary to cast the result of `where` into an `Array` in `Pgdb::getInfo`. The `where` query returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that responds to `each`, as well as other `Enumerable` messages like `map` and `select`, similarly to an array. In your code, you are successfully iterating over the result set in

```
<% @info.each do |row| %>
```

This will work whether you use `to_a` or not in `getInfo`. There are good reasons *not* to cast your result set to an array. For one, `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects have other capabilities, like scoping, which you may often need to use.

Hope that helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to connect rails to an external database is using the `config/database.yml` file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  template: template0

# used for test & development
local:
  host: localhost
  username: j_random_user # change this!
  password: p4ssword # change this!

development:
  <<: *defaults
  <<: *local
  database: my_app_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *defaults
  <<: *local
  database: my_app_test

production:
  <<: *defaults
  host: "my_app_something.rds.amazonaws.com" # change this!
  username: my_amazon_db_user # change this!
  password: my_amazon_user # change this!
  reconnect: true
  port: 3306
```

You may want to use a local postgres database for development and mirror the production database with pgbackups.

But your main issue is that your are doing pretty much everything wrong when it comes to creating a rails application. That looks like a PHP example where some clueless soul is reinventing an database manager for the 1000th time.

### So here is a fast Rails MVC & ActiveRecord crash course:

Models reflect the objects in your domain. Lets say we have a pet store app.

We of course need a Pet model:

```
$ rails g model Pet name:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

This creates a `pets` table in the database and a `Pet` class. Note that the table name is plural and the model name is singular.

```
# app/models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

We can then access the pets by:

```
Pet.all
Pet.find(1) # find pet where id is 1
# ... etc
```

And we can create pets by:

```
pet = Pet.create(name: "Spot")
```

All of this is covered in most [basic rails tutorials](https://www.railstutorial.org/).

## Connecting without a model.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
con = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
res = con.execute('SELECT * FROM foo')
```

Although using ActiveRecord does not really make sense if you are not actually using a model per table and following the MVC conventions somewhat. It's possible, but it gives you no real benefits at all.

Likewise doing Rails without MVC is doable but what's the point?

## Using a legacy database

let's say you have a legacy database written by someone who though using Apps Hungarian for database columns (shrug) was cool:

```
persons:
  intPersonID: Integer, Autoincrement, Primary Key
```

And you want to map this to a Rails model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name 'persons'
   self.primary_key 'intPersonID'
 end
```

Or in your case:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name 'test' # since it's not "tests"
end

Test.where(city: "New York")
```

Comment: Maybe my post isn't clear...I have complex external database that isn't necessarily specific to my rails app. I am just using rails to display and make sense of the information in the database. I absolutely have a `config/database.yml` with the external database params, but how do you actually connect to it outside of a model? I am interested in the answer because I haven't made many rails apps, although it doesn't have much to do with my original question of rendering an ActiveRecord relation.

Comment: I have added an example of how to connect without a model.